# Сортирующий индекс

Tags: sql-server

> Важной характеристикрй кластерного индекса является, то что все значения в нем отсортированы по возрастанию либо убыванию 
>   Объясните, пожалуйста, значения сортируются по внутреннему индексу, по величине(например для числовых типов) или по алфавиту (для строчных типов)?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наоборот - тип данных определяет сортировку.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, при добавлении нового значения в столбец который например упорядочен по алфавиту и по row id, что здесь первично алфавит или указатель на строку с данными?

Comment: *при добавлении нового значения в столбец который например упорядочен* Таблица - это куча. Никакого "упорядочен" в ней нет.

Comment: То есть для некластерного индекса например как на картине на самом деле упорядоченности по именам нет, а лишь по индексу или по индексу тоже нет?

Comment: Индекс - это упорядоченные по выражению индекса ссылки на записи. И только в кластерном индексе в качестве ссылки используется сама запись.